# PDF encryption using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a requirement for creating pdf from existing pdf. Where an existing pdf is copied into a new pdf and new pdf will be password protected(file open password).

I can do it using PHP mpdf. Just want to know if it is possible with nodejs.

Requirements are simple:

1- Copy existing pdf into new pdf.
2- Password protect new pdf.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is open ended without one possible single answer other than "yes" and can have far too many possible answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please suggest a nodejs library having these options, just like mpdf in php

Comment: Asking for library suggestions is not allowed on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible to `Encrypt` PDF in `nodejs` using [QPDF](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/).

### Steps:

#### 1.Install :

Install QPDF on your machine/server using following command

```
sudo apt-get install qpdf
```

or

```
brew install qpdf
```

#### 2.Check whether it is working or not

```
qpdf --encrypt user-password owner-password key-length flags -- source-file-path destination-file-path
```

For example:

```
qpdf --encrypt test test 40 -- Downloads/1.pdf Downloads/encrypted.pdf
```

Now,

i.Try to open the **encrypted.pdf** file in the Downloads folder.

ii. It will ask for password, Enter password **test** which is given while encrypting the PDF file. Now you can able to open the file which means QPDF is working.

#### How to do it in nodejs?

You can do the same in nodejs using [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) or [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs)

#### Code:

```
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;
 var cmd = 'qpdf --encrypt test test 40 -- Downloads/1.pdf Downloads/encryptpdfvianode.pdf';

 exec(cmd, function (err){
       if (err){
          console.error('Error occured: ' + err);
       }else{
          console.log('PDF encrypted :)');
       }
 });
```

`Note:` You can also look at [node-qpdf](https://github.com/nrhirani/node-qpdf) npm package.

Comment: How can I encrypt a pdf create using html-pdf like a buffer ?

Comment: Dont USE QPDF IF YOU HAVE A WINDOWS SYSTEM

Comment: Thank @Hector. I have struggling with `node-qpdf` for some time but had not installed `qpdf` yet, so `sudo apt-get install qpdf` did the trick.

@ShashankSaxena why not? Does that apply to WSL as well?

Comment: same question @Hector, is there a way to encrypt a generated pdf buffer

Comment: I made this creating a pdf as buffer using _const buffer = await pify(pdf.create(html, this.options)).toBuffer();_ then encrypt using _createWriter_ and _PDFRStreamForBuffer_ from npm package called __muhammara__